# Zero-inflated Poisson with known inflation probability

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, zero-inflation

I have a zero-inflated probit model but I know the inflation probability of each observation. So my model is:

$P(y_i = 0|X) = (1-\pi_i) + \pi_i*(1-\Phi(X_i'\beta))$

$P(y_i = 1|X) = \pi_i*\Phi(X_i'\beta)$

and I know what $\pi_i$ is for each observation. Is there a way to estimate the model in R with `zeroinfl()` or `glm()`?

Comment: Are you saying `π` is a known constant, or `π` is a known random effect, or `π` is a known categorical variable (i.e., you have `n` groups and `π` is known for each group)?  Regardless, I imagine it could be coded-up with `optim`.  I do not know about with `glm` or `zeroinfl()`.